# How do i delete remnant build product of Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, macos

I tried to make a widget on Xcode for macOS big sur.
The widget was meant to display the battery level of a bluetooth device connected to my macbook.
I gave up and deleted the project file but this is still there.
I want to get rid of "Bluetooth Battery" and its widget.
Should i go to StackOverflow?
[image]

Comment: What have you done to find and to delete your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built product is usually in Derived data folder of Xcode. The default is `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.

It can be found in Xcode preferences > Locations > Locations > Derived Data.

It can also be found from the `my_project.xcodeproj` > File menu > Project settings > Derived Data.

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/deva52afe8a4

Comment: Found the file and deleted it. Problem solved. Thank you. :)